# error inflating class fragment google maps with google maps

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm new to android development. I've started with something simple, but first step, just displaying a map. 
Here is following steps i did for displaying the map
1) I got google api key, and configure android.mainfest. I  added permissions: MAPS_RECEIVE, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, INTERNET and my google map v2 api key in  element.
2) I imported google-play-services_lib into my workspace. Build it, and add its reference to my project. 
3) Because i used android 2.3.3( api 10), so i used SupportMapFragment instead of MapFragment. Here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ShowMapActivity" >
        <fragment android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment "/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my code in  ShowMapActivity ( it is extended FragmentActivity)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_map);
        if(findViewById(R.id.map)!=null)
        {
            SupportMapFragment fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.map,fragment).commit();
        }
}
```

But unfortunately,when i run app in emulator,  i still get error in log cat : Error inflating class fragment and com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public. 
EDIT: 
Here is my log cat:

```
05-26 13:52:25.457: E/AndroidRuntime(289): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-26 13:52:25.457: E/AndroidRuntime(289): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps/com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.ShowMapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
05-26 13:52:25.457: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
05-26 13:52:25.457: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
05-26 13:52:25.457: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-26 13:52:25.457: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-26 13:52:25.457: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-26 13:52:25.457: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-26 13:52:25.457: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-26 13:52:25.457: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-26 13:52:25.457: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-26 13:52:25.457: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-26 13:52:25.457: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-26 13:52:25.457: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-26 13:52:25.457: E/AndroidRuntime(289): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
05-26 13:52:25.457: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)
05-26 13:52:25.457: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
05-26 13:52:25.457: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
05-26 13:52:25.457: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
05-26 13:52:25.457: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
05-26 13:52:25.457: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
05-26 13:52:25.457: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
05-26 13:52:25.457: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.ShowMapActivity.onCreate(ShowMapActivity.java:22)
05-26 13:52:25.457: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-26 13:52:25.457: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
05-26 13:52:25.457: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  ... 11 more
05-26 13:52:25.457: E/AndroidRuntime(289): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment : make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
```

So how can  i resolve it. Which steps i am missing or did it wrong
Thanks for you help, and sorry everyone because my English writting skill is bad

Comment: please add your logcat

Comment: @thepoosh : thanks for you reply, here is my logcat:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps/com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.ShowMapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
....
05-26 13:52:25.457: E/AndroidRuntime(289): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment : make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public

Comment: @thepoosh: I editted my question

Answer (score 0):

I have once have exactly the same problem. The problem was connected with... too long file path to library.

It seems google-play-services_lib is too deeply nested in folder structure sometimes. Try copy it to other location.

Answer (score 0):

In case you didn't found a solution, make sure that the activity where the SupportMapFragment should be loaded extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity